# CakePHP4: Link to Json File in Script

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, cakephp

I have a CakePHP4 App where I create a D3JS WorldMap in a `<script>` tag. I need to link to a JSON File in this line       `d3.json("https://api.jsonbin.io/b/61f8ec14518e5f3b2ab3e218", function(error, topology) {` but this time its saved in `webroot folder`.

I have tried to get the Path `console.log('<?php echo WWW_ROOT; ?>');` but it didnt work. How can I set the Path to my file over JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I set the Path to my file over JavaScript?

```
path: "<?= $this->Url->build('/my.json', ['fullBase' => true]); ?> "

// Output
// path: "http://somedomain.com/my.json"
```

or:

```
<div data-json="<?= $this->Url->build('/my.json', ['fullBase' => true]); ?>" ></div>
```

then in your js read data attribute

Read more:
https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/url.html